# ConcurrentModification with List<List<>>

Tags: java

I am using java 8 and NetBean 8.1. I have reviewed a bunch of the similar concurrentModification postings and don't understand what I am doing wrong.

This is a simple version of the logic but the goal is to take a roster of players, divide them into equal groups and randomly take one person per group for each team. The logic seems reasonable but no matter what type of loop, whether I accumulate the team members and remove them later, etc. I keep causing the same ConcurrentModification Exception.

What is wrong with this strategy?

```
    static int numberOfTeams = 10;
static int numberPerTeam = 4;

private static List<String> testConcurrentMod() {
    List<String> teams = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i=0; i<(numberOfTeams*numberPerTeam); ++i) {
        list.add(i);
    }
    List<List<Integer>> poolList = divideField(list, numberPerTeam);

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTeams; ++i) {
        List<Integer> members = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Iterator<List<Integer>> iterator = poolList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
            List<Integer> pool = iterator.next();
            int index = randomNumber(0, pool.size()-1);
            members.add(pool.remove(index));
        }
        String t = members.stream().map(m -> String.valueOf(m)).collect(Collectors.joining(", "));
        teams.add(t);
    }
    return teams;
}

private static List<List<Integer>> divideField(List<Integer> list, int noOfPools) {
    List<List<Integer>> pools = new ArrayList<>();
    int poolAllocation = list.size() / noOfPools;

    for (int i = 0; i < noOfPools; ++i) {
        int startPos = i * poolAllocation;
        int endPos = startPos + poolAllocation;
        pools.add(list.subList(startPos, endPos));
    }

    return pools;
}
```

As requested here is the complete stack track. The line of code is the randomNumber() call but using the NetBeans debugger the exception is identified with the first call to pool.remove

```
    Warning:   #{events.manage.autoGenerateTeams()}: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
javax.faces.FacesException: #{events.manage.autoGenerateTeams()}: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.clubscoring.util.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 43 more
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1231)
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.size(ArrayList.java:1040)
    at com.clubscoring.util.TeamGen.testConcurrentMod(TeamGen.java:192)
    at com.clubscoring.util.TeamGen.create(TeamGen.java:36)
    at com.clubscoring.web.pages.EventManage.autoGenerateTeams(EventManage.java:511)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 44 more

Severe:   javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.glassfish.tyrus.servlet.TyrusServletFilter.doFilter(TyrusServletFilter.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at com.clubscoring.util.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:282)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:175)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:561)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:565)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:545)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:1231)
    at java.util.ArrayList$SubList.size(ArrayList.java:1040)
    at com.clubscoring.util.TeamGen.testConcurrentMod(TeamGen.java:192)
    at com.clubscoring.util.TeamGen.create(TeamGen.java:36)
    at com.clubscoring.web.pages.EventManage.autoGenerateTeams(EventManage.java:511)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:332)
    at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:537)
    at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:283)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
    ... 44 more
```

Comment: You're using `pool.remove`, which invalidates the iterator on it. That's the source of your problem. Can you elaborate on what exactly you're trying to achieve? Why do you need to remove elements from `pool`?

Comment: @Mureinik that's what I initially thought - however, whilst `pool` comes *from* an iterator, but it doesn't actually have an iterator over it. At least not that I have spotted.

Comment: In the example I am grouping 40 players in to 4 lists of 10 - think of it as A, B, C, D skill levels. To build a team I picking one player from each skill level and removing them because they have been allocated to a team. If I changed the top structure A,B,C,D I would understand the exception but I am changing the content. I even captured the index and removed them outside the loop with the same error.

Comment: It’s not clear which line of that code would cause a ConcurrentModificationException.  Please edit your question and include the exception’s entire stack trace.  And it would be helpful if you also stated which line of the code you’re showing us corresponds to the first line of the stack trace.

Comment: @VGR:  With one tweak to the random function, this code is runnable locally.

Comment: someone downvoted this post without giving a real reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're definitely modifying the underlying element.  What you're getting back isn't a *pure* `ArrayList<Integer>`, but you' *are* getting back something that conforms to the contract of `List<Integer>` - namely, you're getting back an instance of `ArrayList$SubList`.

Instead of working out the intricacies as to why you're not getting back a proper `ArrayList`, you should simply force the result you get back from the `Iterator` into a new `ArrayList`, one which is safe to modify.

```
List<Integer> pool = new ArrayList<>(iterator.next());
```

From here, your code will no longer throw the `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: ahhh I am probably using sublist wrong. I am appearing to work on 'poolList' which is why I didn't understand the error.  But if I am using sublist wrong and 'list' is still the underlying structure then the exception makes sense. This is probably the correct answer but I want to apply the fix before marking it as such.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you create multiple sublists and then manipulate them. According to the javadoc (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList(int,%20int))

> The semantics of the list returned by this method become undefined if the backing list (i.e., this list) is structurally modified in any way other than via the returned list. (Structural modifications are those that change the size of this list, or otherwise perturb it in such a fashion that iterations in progress may yield incorrect results.)

So if you call pool.remove() on one sublist, all the other sublists become invalid and will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` on any access.

The solution is to replace

```
pools.add(list.subList(startPos, endPos));
```

with

```
pools.add(new ArrayList<>(list.subList(startPos, endPos)));
```